# Why is the Egyptian government building a new capital instead of modernizing and fixing Cairo?

Tags: corruption, egypt

[Egypt is building a new capital 45 km away from Cairo.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0JY3D0IrQ8)

Why is the Egyptian government building a new capital instead of modernizing and fixing Cairo?

Is it because the government wants to embezzle money?

Comment: Government *always* wants to embezzle money. That's like a basic background fact of life :)

Comment: Won't have time for a full answer but have you seen Cairo? It's **hard** to modernize and fix super megalopolises that have organically grown and sprawled through centuries (never mind millenia, like Cairo). It's ALWAYS easier to start from scratch, ask any software developer :)

Comment: @user4012, `It's ALWAYS easier to start from scratch, ask any software developer :)` --- yeah, unless you are taking a Chinese loan to write a software.

Comment: @user4012, `It's hard to modernize and fix super megalopolises that have organically grown and sprawled through centuries` --- what about cities like Rome or Athens?

Comment: "unless you are taking a Chinese loan to write a software" - *\*cough\** Google *\*cough\** Project Dragonfly *\*cough\**

Comment: @user4012, that is not a loan. that is investment.

Comment: @anonymous: Well, what about Rome and Athens?  Do you think it would be possible to fix them at less cost than starting anew?

Comment: Athens is not a counterexample: it was a very small town at the time of Greek independence, and not even the first choice for capital.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you seem to be asking for the official reason(s)... Quoting mostly from a spokesman for the project, Khaled El-Husseiny, as [reproduced in the Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/cities/2018/may/08/cairo-why-egypt-build-new-capital-city-desert):

> The project is designed to wipe clean the problems of Cairo, and build a glistening new future. [...]
>
> Last month, inside the glass-walled offices of the Administrative Capital for Urban Development (ACUD), the company overseeing the project, El-Husseiny attempts to explain. ACUD is 51% owned by the Egyptian military – El-Husseiny is a former major general – as is the land for the new capital. The remaining 49% of ACUD is controlled by Egypt’s ministry of housing. [...]
>
> “In Brazil it was Rio and it became Brasília – we need this. It costs billions, we know, but we need it,” says El-Husseiny, referencing Oscar Niemeyer and Lúcio Costa’s landmark project to build a new capital in Brazil, now regarded as a symbol of the failure of urban planning and inequality. It is hoped Egypt’s new capital will house almost twice the population of Brasília, while paradoxically appealing to incomers as a way to escape Cairo’s crowded street life. [...]
>
> “We will give them benefits not available in the old Cairo, wide streets and a smart city,” he says, going on to outline something quite dystopian: “A smart city means a safe city, with cameras and sensors everywhere. There will be a command centre to control the entire city.”
>
> “Cairo isn’t suitable for the Egyptian people,” says El-Husseiny. “There are traffic jams on every street, the infrastructure can’t support the population, and it’s very crowded. Without any specific masterplan, it has started to become ugly … there’s no humanity.”
>
> But El-Husseiny is adamant. “We need a landmark, a new capital. We have the right to have a dream and this is our dream.”

I may sound trite and cynical, but reading between the lines:  a military-owned capital, full of "smart" security, and free of congestion caused by ordinary people seems to high on the list of reasons. And the old capital is ugly, it seems.

And yea, I'm not the only one to [conclude](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/world/egypt-builds-new-capital-city-replace-cairo-n893606) that:

> In the new capital, “the army will be in the command and control center and will manage and control the whole city via the center,” Soliman said.
>
> That could help insulate the government from the threat of a popular uprising, analysts say.

And also to show off the achievements of the [military rule](https://doi.org/10.1080/13530194.2017.1363956):

> “What the army — and Egypt — know how to do is build things,” said Michele Dunne, the director of the Middle East Program at the Carnegie Endowment for International Peace, a think tank based in Washington. “Whether it's roads or buildings they have access to state-owned land, which is vast and they can cut through bureaucracy. Building is their way of showing accomplishments.”

Although in this respect, that article also notes that Egypt has had some not so successful experiments in the past: [Sadat City](https://www.gulf-times.com/story/439517/Sadat-City-is-a-cautionary-tale-as-Egypt-plans-new), built half-way between Cairo and Alexndaria. Note that Sadat City was never meant to be a new capital, but [part](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43029127) of five new satellite cities for Cairo, back then a plan to reduce congestion/concentration in Cairo, among other things. An [Egyptian paper from 2009](http://www.cpas-egypt.com/pdf/Ettouney&Nasamat/E&N/ARCHCAIRO%202009,%20New%20Communities%20in%20Egypt,%203%20decades%20later.pdf) on these new cities concluded:

> Most of those new settlements were planned to reach target size and population
> within 15 to 25 years. The reviewed satellite images showed that most of the new urban
> settlements are clearly lagging behind the planned targets. The few that are actively
> developing, mostly in and near Greater Cairo, reflect serious deviations from original policies
> and development plans; hence adding to the problems rather than alleviating the burdens of
> the Primate City and region.

They note that (for instance) Sadat City ended up being more of an industrial city where a lot of people commute to work rather than live there as well.

As to the last part of your question on embezzlement, it's hard to speak of classical corruption anymore (even though it probably continues), when the military is basically running quite a few things, [including companies](https://www.reuters.com/investigates/special-report/egypt-economy-military/):

> Figures from the Ministry of Military Production - one of three main bodies that oversee military firms - show that revenues at its firms are rising sharply. The ministry’s figures and the chairmen’s accounts give rare insight into the way the military is growing in economic influence. [...]
>
> The International Monetary Fund warned in Sept. 2017 that private sector development and job creation “might be hindered by involvement of entities under the Ministry of Defense.”
>
> Egypt’s government counters that private companies are operating on an even playing field and that the military is filling gaps in the market, as it did during a shortage of infant formula in 2016. Then the military helped by importing supplies and has since announced plans to build a formula plant. Sisi says the military can deliver large, complicated projects faster than the private sector.
>
> In 2016, the military and other security institutions were given exemptions in a new value-added tax (VAT) law enacted as part of IMF-inspired reforms. The law states that the military does not have to pay VAT on goods, equipment, machinery, services and raw materials needed for the purposes of armament, defense and national security.
>
> The Ministry of Defense has the right to decide which goods and services qualify. Civilian businessmen complain that this can leave the system open to abuse. Receipts for a cup of coffee at private sector hotels, for example, add 14 percent VAT. Receipts at military hotels do not. Employees at the military-owned Al-Masah Hotel in Cairo told Reuters that no VAT was charged when renting venues for weddings and conferences. [...]
>
> Estimates vary on the scale of the military’s role in the economy. Sisi said in Dec. 2016 the military accounts for up to two percent of output. "It has been said that the military’s economy is worth 20 or even 50 percent of the economy. I wish,” he said at the opening of a military facility to produce chlorine for water sanitation.
>
> A leading political scientist, who asked not to be named, put the figure at about three percent of GDP. [...]
>
> The chairman of one firm that falls under the Ministry of Military Production, Major General Mammdouh Badawy, recalled with distaste the days of economic liberalization under President Hosni Mubarak in the 1990s and mid 2000s when “businessmen were eating up the country.”   Badawy’s enterprise, Heliopolis Co. for Chemical Industries, was set up in 1949 to produce hand grenades, mortars, fuses and chemicals. These days it has ambitions to become Egypt’s number one supplier of paint.

So the new capital and the way it is being built are part of this military-centric model. The same article also mentions that a military-owned company is also building the largest cement factory in the country, no doubt in relation to the building of the new capital.

Answer (score 2):

Answer 1: It's more expensive to raze some buildings and build on top of them, than to build new buildings on flat land.

Answer 2: For the same reasons for which Brazil built Brasilia in the 1960's. Brazil was very corrupt and poor at that time, in the 1960's. Brasilia is now the most affluent and 3rd most populous city in Brazil.

Answer 3: There is no free space in the 2nd most dense mega-city, after Bombay, under every bridge and on every rooftop, there are dozens of families. In the new city, there is only flat empty land.

Answer 4: You'd probably have to evict 300,000 people to strive for a Cairo less fluid and spacious than Mexico City.

Dozens of people live in individual tombs in the necropolis, sometimes the necropolis homes have a fridge and a TV. The planners have to route around the Necropolis's and mosques.

Answer 5: Land was nationalized in 1950, and ownership of land was banned, Cairo is a dense real estate anarchy. In the new city, there are no legal quandaries.

People have built homes and taken land as best they can, without property titles.

Cairo land titles and planning permissions are undemocratic, super corrupt and difficult to regulate.

Answer 6: Serious traffic problems which make Cairo the second most polluted megacity in the world, after Delhi, average travel speed is about 20Kph. Why try to fix a city with 20kph traffic? for a few billion pounds, the average travel speed will rise to 25kph. Those same billion pounds can make average speed 40Kph in a new city.

Answer 7: There was already a revolution with mass protests in Cairo, there is clearly a need for peripheral urban axes near to Cairo.

Building a new city from scratch can actually work, as seen in Dubai and Brasilia.